# Can't connect to an avd

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code, flutter

I'm trying to run the code template as my first attempt to work with flutter. I've setted a device with the android studio emulator with charasteristics as follows:

Nexus 5x - api 25 - Nougat 7.1 arm64

I'm working on an amd processor in windows 8.1 aswell. The main issue is when I try to run the emulator inside vs code. It launches the device but after a while it throws the next error:

+Failed to launch emulator: Error: Emulator didn't connected within 60 seconds
Origen: Dart

Even when I try to run the app from android studio it doesn't connect, and doesn't even gives some error message.

I would appreciate any help or recommendation to finally start working with flutter.

Flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows 
[VersiÃ³n 6.3.9600], locale es-CL)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices      
(Android SDK 28.0.3)
X Android license status unknown.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.29.1)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: what does`adb devices` return

Comment: On the terminal, in the root folder of the project, what is the outcome of `flutter run`?

Comment: after changing the boot mode to cold boot, restarting the adb server and running the app from vs code, it now connects to the device, but throws adb not responding and exits.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857495/8350143

Comment: I found this was caused after I had changed some settings within the android folder. Can check by creating a new project and copying over the android folder

Answer (score 2):

> Emulator didn't connected within 60 seconds

This error is reported by the Dart plugin for VS Code if it launches an emulator but the emulator does not show up in `flutter devices` within 60 seconds.

First I'd try killing the ADB server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

If that doesn't help, try launching the emulator outside of VS Code (eg. using `flutter emulators --launch`) and then seeing whether it turns up in `flutter devices` from the terminal. If not, then see if it shows up in `adb devices`.

If it *does* show up in `flutter devices` when running it manually, please file a bug against the Dart plugin [here](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) but otherwise, please file a bug against [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter) and cc me (@DanTup) and I'll see what I can find.

Comment: thank.. but in which console we have to run this adb kill command, I tried in VS code terminal & it says adb is not recognised. Please help

Comment: You should be able to run it in any terminal. If the built-in terminal says it's not recognised, there may be an issue with the Android SDK not being in your PATH correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Run **$flutter doctor --android-licenses**

Then accept all the licenses you haven't before. It should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, you can run **flutter doctor --android-licenses**.

After that, it will prompt you to select (y/n) to the licenses.

Press 'Y' until the licenses are all accepted. I had a similar issue and this worked for me.