# Unable to launch android emulator. It gives me no avd specified

Tags: android-studio, flutter, sdk, android-emulator, adb

When I try to open emulator in Android studio. It gives me "unable to find adb" error also I tried to launch by cmd which is

```
cd C:\Users\EFE\Desktop\sdk\tools
emulator.exe
```

It gives me

```
emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'
```

I deleted my SDK Platform-Tools and reinstall it. 
I don't have Android files in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` to fix it.
In my case it is `C:\Users\EFE\AppData\Local\Android Open Source Project\Emulator` and it doesn't have any platform-tools. I used the emulator yesterday perfectly. I think I played a game that has a protection program. I disabled the protection program but didn't solve my problem.

Reinstall the android studio and flutter but still have the same problem. When I try to open emulator via AVD manager. It gives me "unable to locate adb" and trying to open emulator but just black screen.

Answer (score 1):

option 1:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_64
```

option 2:

```
emulator "@Pixel_2_64"
```

Have to use the quotation marks or use the avd flag.

@ is used for argument splatting in PowerShell, hence the need for quoting; alternatively, you could have -escaped the @ (emulator @Pixel_2_64)

Comment: I used "emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29" and error is "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU."

Comment: can you try `cd C:\Users\EFE\Desktop\sdk\emulator\emulator.exe` and see whether it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your emulator width :

```
emulator -avd <name>
```

If not working, I create a `.bat` file on github for you : https://github.com/samuel3105/Android-AVD-windows.
You just have to launch the `.bat` file, type `1` to show your emulator, and enter the name of your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wipe the data of the particular device.

Go to -> Android Studio -> Tools -> AVD Manager -> [Select the down triangle on your chosen device] -> Wipe data.

Now retry.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814027/11283638