# Unable to connect android emulator with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I recently installed flutter in my pc. I am running flutter in Visual Studio Code. I am trying to run android emulator but to my vain I am getting the following error whenever I am trying to run android emulator:-

```
Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 25: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds
```

I even deleted the existing android emulator from android studio and created a fresh one but, then also, the issue is not resolved.

I also tried the flutter emulator but, then also, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to launch emulator: Error: Emulator didn't connected within 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677874/failed-to-launch-emulator-error-emulator-didnt-connected-within-60-seconds)

Comment: I have already tried all the processes as mentioned in the above link before but nothing worked previously for which I raised my doubt here @dm_tr

Answer (score 1):

Try to run an emulator with higher API level ( API 26 or higher )

Comment: Ok I wil try. Thanks for helping