# Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 31: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds (Flutter Project on VS Code in a Apple Silicon Mac)

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, apple-m1, apple-silicon

i have been trying to run my flutter project on my Pixel 2 Android Emulator (On my Apple Silicon Macbook), and i get the error:

`Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 31: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds`

But at the same time, my android emulator opens up on my Mac, so i think the issue is that the android emulator is not getting connected with VS Code.

The flutter application runs smoothly on both my IOS Stimulator and my physical huawei android phone with no issues at all.

Is this because of the Apple Silicon Chip or any general issue?

If anyone knows the fixture for this, let me know.

Lemme know if you need any further details or if you are not clear about my question.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677874/failed-to-launch-emulator-error-emulator-didnt-connect-within-60-seconds)

Comment: I was able to run the project via android studio, instead of VS Code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Open `AVD Manager` on the top right of `Android Studio`.
3. Select the actions (for the emulator you are trying to launch) and if the `stop` option is available to be pressed, click the `stop` button (What you are trying is, to quit your emulator if it's already running), and if the emulator is already stopped, now click on the `Wipe Data`.
4. Now try running project on your emulator. This worked for me.

Reference : [Failed to launch emulator: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677874/failed-to-launch-emulator-error-emulator-didnt-connect-within-60-seconds)