# available devices and emulators in the Flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, emulation

I want to run Flutter but the emulation I installed is not available in vs code. When I run the emulator, the emulator comes up, but the program does not run in it, only the programs run in Android Studio run in it.

[image: image description here]

Comment: Can you describe what you;ve tried on vs code to open emulators? Can you find any device after running `flutter enulators`

Comment: I just select the installed emulator and click run, the emulator comes up but the program doesn't run, I have this problem only with the installed emulator, the others work fine, like the physical device and the browser.
It also gives this error when running the simulator
Failed to launch Pixel 4 API 31: Error: Emulator did not connect within 60 seconds

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55677874/10157127) answer your question

Comment: This can't help me because there is no stop option for me

Comment: can you  run `flutter emulators` on terminal and share the info

Comment: it's output: To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

Comment: seems like there is no emulator device detected, else you would see the list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delete your emulator from avd folder and then create one again.
Also, try to run the project after running the emulator in android studio. Completely delete the folder of the installed emulator.

The emulator's folder is generally: USER/USERNAME/.android/avd

Comment: I did this, but I encountered this error: ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)

Comment: delete all emulator folders in avd folder then restart computer and recreate emulator in android studio.