# Emulator works in Android Studio but not VS Code

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm running emulated devices in android studio just fine, but when i try running it in VS Code, I'm get this error: "Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 27: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds"

saw some videos and guides, but they all say to reinstall the emulator or wipe the emulated device, which doesn't help.

what could be the problem?

trying to use this for a flutter project that i'm trying to create, and it kind hurts testing.

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem is the same as this

> Steps:
>
> Open Android Studio Tools -> AVD Manager Virtual Device -> Actions (Refer Image) Click On Stop Now Start Emulator Now it's working fine :)

or please visit that link [Failed to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677874/failed-to-launch-emulator-error-emulator-didnt-connect-within-60-seconds)`

Comment: Welcome Muh. andika Rusli. You've sufficient reputation to be able to flag a question as having answers elsewhere (flag as duplicate, then paste the target's URL into the field).

Comment: there is no stop for me in the avd manager. that solution might have been for an older version of android studio. i tried creating a new device, so i didn't even start it (so no need to stop) and i still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the only way to run the emulator, is to run the device in Android studio, and then run the app in visual code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).